# How can remove or Ignore variable of Swagger in spring boot (Swagger 3.0)

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, api, swagger

I have some problem when I using swagger 3.0  in Spring boot
I need to remove some of variables in swagger but `@ApiIgnore` and `@Hidden` is not working
It still showing like blow , even if I put `@ApiIgnore` and `@Hidden`..

kindly help me
Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
```

Comment: Solution is @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solved the problem.